# Don't split between specific characters

Tags: c#, string, split, character

Currently, I'm using this code to split a string:

`string[] split = source.Split(new char[] { ' ' });`

So "The quick /little brown/ fox" would be:

`The
quick
/little
brown/
fox`

And what I want is this:

`The
quick
/little brown/
fox`

I have seen some solutions (and I don't really understand them) but they all go into a `var` and I want it to go into a `string[]`.

Comment: You could hardly do that without a regex. Do you have to use Split or can you use regexes?

Comment: A `var` CAN be a `string[]`.  A `var` is whatever your method returns.  If your method returns a string array, then its a string array.

Comment: It's ok to use regexes if I need to.

Comment: If you have any control over the creation of the string you want to split I'd suggest using something other than a space for your delimiter and splitting on that. A pipe `|` is perfect for this since it's not something that gets used very often. If you don't have control, I'd go with @Louis and suggest using a regex instead of `.Split()`.

Comment: Why is it _too broad_?

Comment: The problem is I don't have any control over the creation of the string because the user enters it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I voted too broad because the question has nothing specific other than the raw problem description. The problem can be solved in a variety of ways but we don't know any particular circumstances that would help picking one or another.

Comment: @xxbbcc: in my opinion the question is clear and specific. So i would understand if it would have been closed because there is a duplicate (for sure) but not because it's "too broad".

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I remove the sample text from the question all that's left is essentially "do this for me". I don't think that's what the author intended but there's no effort shown. I agree that the desired end result is clear but I don't think this is a clear question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex for this:

```
string s = "The quick /little brown/ fox";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(s, @"((/.+/)|(\b\w+\b))").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Output:

```
The
quick
/little brown/
fox
```

Comment: One might want to make the `/.../` match non-greedy, since the way the regex is written, splitting something like `a /b c/ d /e f/ g` is likely to give you `a`, `/b c/ d /e f/` and `g` rather than the expected `a`, `/b c/`, `d`, `/e f/` and `g`. Just sayin' ...